# drupal move specific field to another field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I basically have a content type named "articles", and in this content type there is a reference field (that let me put unlimited data) called `authorsref` and a text field which as well let's me add as many as I want.

Both of this fields are called "authors".

What I want to do is move a specific reference field, to the text field, and then delete that reference field.

So for example, there are a hundred articles already, there are actually thousands and let's say 40 of them have a reference field with the author `test1` amongst other reference fields and let's say as well that 60 of those hundred articles have as well a reference field of `test2`.

what I need to do is to somehow go over all the articles and where `test1` and `test2` reference fields are present, move them from the reference field `authorsref` to the text field `authors`.

I am as well a newbie and I have been trying to get this to work for the last three days and I just don't know how.

Please help, and thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `hook_update_n` + `batch`.

`hook_update_n` - With this hook you can update some values in your DB.

`Batch` - you need to use batch for operations that may take a long time. (You don't want to time out PHP, you wont worry about it with batch).

Some examples [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/examples-for-database-update-scripts-using-hook_update_n-how) and [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example%21batch_example.install/function/batch_example_update_7100/7.x-1.x).

Comment: Thanks so much for this, although I am a super newbie and have no idea how to do that, is there a video tutorial or something or an easier way to do this? thanks so much!

Comment: @Kevin Do you have problems with batch and update? Or you don't know how to work with nodes programmatically?

Comment: Hi @wau, I guess both, I've never used batch and update and I've done some templates and played around with nodes but not that much, sorry; any help would be great :)

Comment: @Kevin In this case you need to find how to use "EntityFieldQuery" for getting needed nodes by your conditions. After it you need to google how to update nodes programmatically. And I've provided above links for hook_update and batch. It's not hard. I hope you will succeed